# Difference of IDBSet and DBSet

Tags: entity-framework

I am developing a project, dealing with saving to database, but it seems that using DBSet is faster than IDBSet, I want to know if there are any risks. What are the differences?

```
private readonly IDbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;
foreach (TEntity entity in entities)
{
    _dbSet.Remove(entity);
}

And
private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;
_dbSet.RemoveRange(entities);
```

Comment: There's no way that `IDBSet` is faster, how did you come up with that measurement? One is an interface and the other is a concrete class that implements the interface.

Comment: I used with IDBSet, the execution speed for a case of saving data to the database is about 42 seconds, while DBSet takes 12 seconds